# How to switch view programmatically with Infopath 2010 on a button click

Tags: infopath

I want to switch view in an Infopath form after a button click.

I tried that but didn't work :

```
    public void BTN_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            this.Submit();  // anonymous user, work like a charm
            this.ViewInfos.SwitchView("Soumis"); // switch view here, doesn't work
        });
    }
```

The error message says that the view is not ready!

Thanks

Comment: Does the view switching absolutely have to happen in code? Could it be done with rules?

Comment: Yes because of the code, the switchview with rules can't work

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with rules. Please see the image below. Add an action to switch the view.

[image]

Comment: Not working with a submit in code behind!!!

Comment: Anyone else have an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default view in the Loading event for the form.

something like this

```
public void FormEvents_Loading(object sender, LoadingEventArgs e) 
{ 
        string view = "";

        if (e.InputParameters.ContainsKey("View")) 
        { 
            view = e.InputParameters["View"]; 
            e.SetDefaultView(view); 
        }

}
```

If you try to use ViewInfos.SwitchView - you'll probably get this error:

**InfoPath cannot execute any view-related object model calls. The view is not ready**

Hence, use the SetDefaultView method on the Load event args.

Comment: The code is not working! I always have the same view after the submit.

Comment: Follow this article : http://johnliu.net/blog/2011/5/27/infopath-formserver-initial-view-and-parameters-via-url.html

Comment: I read the article but cannot find how to do it! Im not an Infopath programmer!